# Problems with multiple tables and sortable columns on the same page

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a problem with three or more tables on the same .gsp page. 
I want to show three tables on one page, both with sortable columns. Unfortunaly that does not work, because variables like sort and order seem to be globally definded and will take effect on every table. 
So if both tables have the column, both are sorted. If one has not, an error is thrown. 
Is there any way to have three tables one  page, which can be independently sorted, or what is a good way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [remote-pagination plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/remote-pagination).

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in our Grails app. I copied the source code of the sortableColumn tag into my own taglib and changed the names of the second table's sort and order params to eg sort2 and order2. Change the names in your new sortableColumn tag accordingly.

Comment: My mistake, I've only done it for the paginate tag. Hence no example but I'm pretty sure the same principles apply. Change all params to new names (including the link parametrs that's generated in the tag) and use the new params in the list/findBy/...-query for the second table. Then do the same for the third table. It's not so Groovy but it works when you get the hang of it.